# Dynamically generating ui:inputSelectOption with data from the server

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong. I'm creating my ui:inputSelectOption elements dynamically - I have an init method in a parent component that gets a list of picklist values of a particular field from the server, and then that list gets passed along through several child components (of which some are inside aura:iterations) into my modal component. In my modal component, I use that list in an aura:iteration to generate several ui:inputSelectOption in my ui:inputSelect. I'm getting the correct data back and I see the desired output (the select options) for the very first instance of my modal component, but the subsequent ones are missing.

Code for init function in controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        ...
        action.setParams({queryString:qs});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var jsonRes = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
            var treeArray = helper.unflatten(jsonRes.listAssignments);
            component.set("v.assignments",treeArray);
            component.set('v.statusOptions', jsonRes.picklistList);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Code in view:

```
<aura:attribute name="statusOptions" type="List" />

    <c:tree header="Assignments" reload="{!c.doInit}" statusOptions="{!v.statusOptions}" />
```

Code in view of child component:

```
<aura:component controller="lightning_Controller">
    <aura:attribute name="statusOptions" type="List" />

     <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectStatus">
     <ui:inputSelectOption text="" label="None" />
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.statusOptions}" var="option">
         <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!option.value}" label="{!option.label}" />
      </aura:iteration>
  </ui:inputSelect>
```

Comment: are you using the child component reference in different apps. From what you have, I populated the selectoptions as shown here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelect.htm and tried to reuse the same parent component multiple times in an app and it worked fine. Could it be possible that you are  missing statusoptions attribute in the other references of the component?